# Why is my number keyboard jumping to a default one. For a moment?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, flutter-debug, flutter-keyboard

Did any of you happen to encounter this bug before? I'm trying to implement OTP for my app project, but during the quick focus change between the 6 fields, Flutter apparently doesn't have enough time to recognize that the keyboards have `TextInputType.number` as keybord type.

This also happens on a physical device.

Here is an example video of the bug: https://drive.google.com/file/d/127dk7OyMpQazLF6b1nQfgIJHBEVXYAJN/view?usp=sharing

Code explanation:
I created 6 textformfields and gave them a initial value of the unicode `\u200b` (except textfield 1), in order to detect if a user pressed delete in an empty textfield.

Here is my code:

```
class enter_safecode extends StatefulWidget {
  const enter_safecode({super.key});

  @override
  State<enter_safecode> createState() => _enter_safecodeState();
}

class _enter_safecodeState extends State<enter_safecode> {

  final _Number1FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? Number1ErrorText; // Variable zur Verfolgung des Fehlermeldungstextes
  TextEditingController _Number1Controller =
  TextEditingController();// Der kann den Zustand des Textfeldes kontrollieren und den eingegebenen Text aufrufen

  final _Number2FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? Number2ErrorText;
  TextEditingController _Number2Controller =
  TextEditingController();

  final _Number3FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? Number3ErrorText;
  TextEditingController _Number3Controller =
  TextEditingController();

  final _Number4FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? Number4ErrorText;
  TextEditingController _Number4Controller =
  TextEditingController();

  final _Number5FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? Number5ErrorText;
  TextEditingController _Number5Controller =
  TextEditingController();

  final _Number6FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? Number6ErrorText;
  TextEditingController _Number6Controller =
  TextEditingController();

  ScrollPhysics CustomScrollPhysics() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0) {
      return BouncingScrollPhysics();
    } else {
      return NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _Number2Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
    _Number3Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
    _Number4Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
    _Number5Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
    _Number6Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: CustomScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 3.5 * globalWidthValue,
                    top: 23.15,
                    bottom: 33.85 * globalHeightValue),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {});
                    } else {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/back_arrow.svg",
                    width: 11 * globalWidthValue,
                    height: 24 * globalHeightValue,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 42 * globalWidthValue,
                ),
              ),
              description(),
              SizedBox(height: 29 * globalHeightValue),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 32.5 * globalWidthValue),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50 * globalWidthValue,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _Number1FormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          maxLength: 1,
                          maxLines: null,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _Number1Controller,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontFamily: "Area", fontSize: calculateFontSize(40)
                          ),
                          //Farbe vom eingegebenen Text
                          onChanged: (value)
                          {
                            if(_Number1Controller.text.length == 1)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                            }
                          },
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                            if(_Number1Controller.text.length == 1)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                              if(_Number2Controller.text.length == 2)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 2)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                  if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 2)
                                  {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                    if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 2)
                                    {
                                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: Text(''),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15 * globalHeightValue, bottom: 16 * globalHeightValue),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld nicht angeklickt ist
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld angeklickt ist
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff40E0D0), width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50 * globalWidthValue,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _Number2FormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          maxLength: 2,
                          maxLines: null,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _Number2Controller,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontFamily: "Area", fontSize: calculateFontSize(40)
                          ),
                          //Farbe vom eingegebenen Text
                          onChanged: (value)
                          {
                            if(value.length == 2)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                            }
                            else if(value.length == 0)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                              setState(() {
                                _Number2Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                              if(_Number2Controller.text.length == 2)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 2)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                  if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 2)
                                  {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                    if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 2)
                                    {
                                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                              else if(_Number1Controller.text.length == 0)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: Text(''),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15 * globalHeightValue, bottom: 16 * globalHeightValue),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld nicht angeklickt ist
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld angeklickt ist
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff40E0D0), width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50 * globalWidthValue,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _Number3FormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          maxLength: 2,
                          maxLines: null,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _Number3Controller,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontFamily: "Area", fontSize: calculateFontSize(40)
                          ),
                          //Farbe vom eingegebenen Text
                          onChanged: (value)
                          {
                            if(value.length == 2)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                            }
                            else if(value.length == 0)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                              setState(() {
                                _Number3Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                              if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 2)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 2)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                  if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 2)
                                  {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                              else if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number2Controller.text.length == 1)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                if(_Number2Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number1Controller.text.length == 0)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                }
                              }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: Text(''),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15 * globalHeightValue, bottom: 16 * globalHeightValue),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld nicht angeklickt ist
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld angeklickt ist
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff40E0D0), width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50 * globalWidthValue,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _Number4FormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          maxLength: 2,
                          maxLines: null,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _Number4Controller,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontFamily: "Area", fontSize: calculateFontSize(40)
                          ),
                          //Farbe vom eingegebenen Text
                          onChanged: (value)
                          {
                            if(value.length == 2)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                            }
                            else if(value.length == 0)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                              setState(() {
                                _Number4Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                              if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 2)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 2)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                }
                              }
                              else if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number3Controller.text.length == 1)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number2Controller.text.length == 1)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                  if(_Number2Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number1Controller.text.length == 0)
                                    {
                                      FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                    }
                                }
                              }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: Text(''),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15 * globalHeightValue, bottom: 16 * globalHeightValue),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld nicht angeklickt ist
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld angeklickt ist
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff40E0D0), width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50 * globalWidthValue,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _Number5FormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          maxLength: 2,
                          maxLines: null,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _Number5Controller,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontFamily: "Area", fontSize: calculateFontSize(40)
                          ),
                          //Farbe vom eingegebenen Text
                          onChanged: (value)
                          {
                            if(value.length == 2)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                            }
                            else if(value.length == 0)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                              setState(() {
                                _Number5Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                              if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 2)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                              }
                              else if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number4Controller.text.length == 1)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number3Controller.text.length == 1)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                  if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number2Controller.text.length == 1)
                                  {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                    if(_Number2Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number1Controller.text.length == 0)
                                    {
                                      FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: Text(''),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15 * globalHeightValue, bottom: 16 * globalHeightValue),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld nicht angeklickt ist
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld angeklickt ist
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff40E0D0), width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50 * globalWidthValue,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _Number6FormKey,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          maxLength: 2,
                          maxLines: null,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _Number6Controller,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontFamily: "Area", fontSize: calculateFontSize(40)
                          ),
                          //Farbe vom eingegebenen Text
                          onFieldSubmitted: (value)
                          {
                            if(value.length == 1)
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                            }
                          },
                          onChanged: (value)
                          {
                            if(value.length == 0)
                            {
                            FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                            setState(() {
                              _Number6Controller = TextEditingController(text: '\u200b');
                            });
                            }
                          },
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                            if(_Number6Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number5Controller.text.length == 1) //Text
                            {
                              FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                              if(_Number5Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number4Controller.text.length == 1)
                              {
                                FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                if(_Number4Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number3Controller.text.length == 1)
                                {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                  if(_Number3Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number2Controller.text.length == 1)
                                  {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                    if(_Number2Controller.text.length == 1 && _Number1Controller.text.length == 0)
                                    {
                                      FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: Text(''),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15 * globalHeightValue, bottom: 16 * globalHeightValue),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld nicht angeklickt ist
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              // Wenn das Feld angeklickt ist
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff40E0D0), width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class description extends StatelessWidget {
  const description({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 19 * globalWidthValue),
          child: Text(
            "Schon da?",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: calculateFontSize(30),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 19.5 * globalWidthValue),
          child: Text(
            "Wir haben dir zur Bestätigung",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: calculateFontSize(20),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 19.5 * globalWidthValue),
          child: Text(
            "deiner E-Mail, eine Nachricht",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: calculateFontSize(20),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 19.5 * globalWidthValue),
          child: Text(
            "gesendet. Bitte gebe den 6-",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: calculateFontSize(20),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 19.5 * globalWidthValue),
          child: Text(
            "Stelligen Code unten ein.",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: calculateFontSize(20),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

- I tried to use a delay before the focus change
- I updated Flutter to the newest Version